# i changed my swappiness from 60 to 10. now it boot

Tags: boot

I was changing my swappiness from 60 to 10, but than after i restarted it, it would not boot by normal means. also i am very new to ubuntu just started using it.

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common Problems:
-boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
-check rootdelay= (did the systemwait long enough)
-check root= (did the systemwait for right device)
-missing modules (cat /proc/modeles; is /dev
Alert /dev/disk/by-uuid/7c303c6e-b0c7-4da0-a80b-c256518730c0 does not exist.
```

this is what i would get everything i boot my laptop.
its a asus apsire E1-531-2453
intel b830 (1.8ghz 2 mb cache l3)
4gb ram
500gbs hdd

& again this was after i changed my swappiness from 60 to 10 than restarted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try booting a livecd, then edit the fstab file on the main drive (/media-some_uuid_or_whatever/etc/fstab) and add a # in front of the entry that mentions swap to comment it and stop it from mounting, then reboot and see if it boots the full installation, if it does, reset the swappiness and try and see if that alone was the issue

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, but the presentation could be improved? Capital letters, full stops?

Comment: sorry, I was binge answering and got a bit sloppy :P

Comment: That's fine, just try to keep it neat :) keep tackling the unanswered ones!

Comment: it took me awhile but i finally got it thank you.